# How to add a textinput value to a value in a dictionary in kivy python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I'm building a simple gui it's a "bank account manager"  and I need to add the value that the user inputs in a textinput in a deposit screen then add it to a balance which the user inputs in the sign up screen .... The sign up screen's info is saved into a dictionary.. each key has a value of a list and that list has 9 values  ...the name, the last name the balance etc...but the balance is a string and I can't even get to it  to run any operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend showing code in an attempt at solving the issue. However to answer your question with the information provided, I would recommend using a button widget and in it's properties in a .kv file use. `on_press:/on_release: root.myfunction()`
then in that screen/application class below use something like this:

```
.kv/Builder_loadstring:
TextInput:
    id: mywidget
    text: 'mywidget'
Button:
    text: 'Run a Function'
    on_release: root.myfunction()

python:
class MyApp(App):
    def myfunction(self):
        *whatever you want it to do*
        value = self.ids.mywidget.text
        *value = self.ids.mywidget.data* #For when you are using lists for recycleview/spinners#
        *value = self.ids.mywidget.some_type_of_widget_property*
        *whatever you want it to do*
```